# Laravel embedded server changing ports

Tags: php, laravel, api, postman, insomnia

[image]

Good day, I'm having this problem with my laravel project, I didn't change anything and just made a postman request to my API and this keeps happening.

I ran `php artisan optimize`, nothing changed.

I updated my linux and nothing happened.

I updated my project and nothing happened.

I don't know what to do...

This is what I get on postman :
[image]

This is what I get on insomnia :
[image]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It was a problem with the version I have installed and it wasn't LTS. I had to create a project and transfer all my code after upgrading all my packages.